# Liquibase call changelogs from multiple jars

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

In my project I'm using maven modules to separate logic. On of those modules is persistence-core (packaged jar) where I've defined liquibases's master change-log. I know that in time I can have some customisations so I've defined some customisation point:

`<includeAll path="${customization-changelog}" relativeToChangelogFile="false" errorIfMissingOrEmpty="false"/>`

In my extension module which is also jar I've defined path `/db/changelog/extension/MASTER` where is my extension's master change-log.

now I'm executing liquibase with property
`customization-changelog=classpath:/db/changelog/extension/MASTER`

but unfortunately it's not executed. Even if I change property to `customization-changelog=classpath*:/db/changelog/extension/MASTER` (classpath*) nothing is executed.

Is it possible to execute liquibase changelogs from within multiple jars?

Comment: Ok it seems to be bug in liquibase. [this](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/pull/608) PR should resolve it.

Comment: what liquibase version did you use? Have you solved the problem?